# amdgpu-pro resolution locked to 800x600

Tags: drivers, video, display-resolution

long atory short I am incredibly new to linux in general and I have an msi laptop making this more of a pain then I woupd like. Fisrslty I was havingg issues starting up my system due to radeon initialisation issues leadingn to crashes at login. I got on to the system using "safe mode" and managed to install the amdgpu-pro drivers (around 3 hours later) and now the resolution is locked to 800x600 and my duel exsternal monitors arnt being detected. any sugestions?

I am running the newest release of Ubuntu studio 16.04.1 and my adapter is

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]
    Kernel modules: radeon
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Neptune XT [Radeon HD 8970M]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Radeon R9 M290X
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? What is the adapter model?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Studio 16.04.1 (the newest release) and I am not sure about the adapter, is there a terminal command I can use to look this up?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: There we go, hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device is not supported by `amdgpu-pro`. It was a mistake to install it. You need to use `radeon` driver that is installed by default.

If you have problems with that driver, you can install Ubuntu 14.04 and use the `fglrx-updates` proprietary driver.

Comment: ok so download and re install 14.04 or can i do this through the current install

Comment: You need to do a fresh install, then run `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am downloading 14.04 now and will post back when I have installed. Thanks for all your help too!

Comment: I have followed the instructions and it has installed but I cant upgrade fglrx because it needs xorg-video-abi-19 but when i go to install that all i get is has no installation candidate